# Looking up a user by id (guid) from within a view in MVC5

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building an invitation based registration system for our site. Essentially the user goes to a page, types in an email, selects a name from a dropdown and hits submit. The link is then emailed to the specified email for the user to register.

I'm running into some issues creating this entire subsystem. Essentially my database table has 5 columns `validation_id` - uniqueidentifier(guid), `all_id` - foreign key to my employees table, `generated_by` - a uniqueidentifier that links to AspNetUsers and gets the user's id, `generated_on` - the date, `email` - the new user's email.

Basically the invitation table has foreign key relationships with two other tables, using `all_id` and `generated_by`. I need to be able to retrieve information from both tables for registration later.

My model for registration_invitations looks like:

```
public partial class registration_invitations
{
    [Key]
    public Guid validation_id { get; set; }

    public int all_id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string generated_by { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Date")]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? generated_on { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

The create view saves everything exactly as I need, but I can't figure out how to get the user that generated the invitation by their id, and I can't seem to get the information from the `all_employees` table.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your table link's screenshot

Comment: What do you mean by table link? You mean my schema?

Comment: @Peo here is a screenshot of my relevant tables - http://imgur.com/dOAN26O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i got this correctly.

The `generated_by` property should points to a foreign key reference to your Users table, so this way EF will generate the right `public User generated_by` property and let you access to the information you want.

Is that what you want to achieve?

EDIT:
You only have to create your tables with the foreign key references in sql server like this:

```
all_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES all_employees(all_id)
generated_by INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AspNetUsers(id)
```

Then Entity Framework do all the job creating the referenced properties you need

Comment: Actually, I have already done that, and EF didn't generate them properly.

Comment: mmm that's weird. Did you properly create the foreign key references?

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming the reason is the fact that I added registration_invites at a later time, so I needed to manually create the foreign key references. Which I just attempted, and it appears to be working, I just had to add an ICollection<registration_invitations> object to my ApplicationUsers model, and an ApplicationUsers object to my registration_invitations object. After that it seems I can pull the required information!

Comment: In the case that you added some changes later, you just need to go to your Model Diagram, right click -> Update Model from Database, and EF will update the model with the changes that you just did

Comment: Even in a code first from database setup? Where is the Model Diagram?